# Android & Google Maps - close info window with back button

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an activity that holds a fragment with Google Map view in it. App adds several dozens of markers to the MapView, using MarkerManager and ClusterRenderer to form clusters.

The problem is that when I have marker's InfoWindow opened and I press hardware Back button, it closes the app. Instead of that, I would like to have the InfoWindow closed.

Is there any straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: without seeing your code, i think u need to override `onBackPressed()`

Comment: That is obvious, but since onBackPressed is activity's method, that would imply passing the info from the MapView through the fragment to the activity, and that would be a bit nasty and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: this may help you if (Marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
     Marker.hideInfoWindow();
    }

Comment: Thx Hasnain, this is what I needed to accomplish this. Posting full solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

I modified MarkerManager to send notification via EventBus when InfoWindow is about to be opened:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View content = fillContent();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MapInfoWindowShownEvent(marker));
    return content;
}
```

and I added event handling in the activity:

```
private Marker mLastShownInfoWindowMarker = null;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mLastShownInfoWindowMarker != null && mLastShownInfoWindowMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        mLastShownInfoWindowMarker.hideInfoWindow();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void onEvent(MapInfoWindowShownEvent event) {
    mLastShownInfoWindowMarker = event.getMarker();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this information I decided to make it a bit simpler for myself:

```
private Marker mLastShownInfoWindowMarker = null;

public void setMLastShownInfoWindowMarker(Marker marker)
  {this.mActiveMapMarker=marker;}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mLastShownInfoWindowMarker != null && mLastShownInfoWindowMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        mLastShownInfoWindowMarker.hideInfoWindow();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Then the following where you have your mapfragment:

```
private MainActivity activity;   // swap this to your activity 

public MainActivityMapController(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
}

// override markerclicklistener to store lastShownInfoWindowMarker in 
// the activity where back button will be used
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            activity.setMLastShownInfoWindowMarker(marker);
            return false; // false keeps the standard behavior
        }
    });
```